# How to Merge All File in other Folder into One File and add newline

Tags: linux, merge, terminal

I have lot of folders and files, this is the structures I have

```
26-09-2016/CHANGELOG_20160926.TXT
26-09-2016/FILE_CHANGELOG_20160926.TXT
27-09-2016/CHANGELOG_20160927.TXT
27-09-2016/FILE_CHANGELOG_20160927.TXT
```

I need to output like that.
All the file with name `CHANGELOG_*.TXT` will be merging and add separate new line into one file like `CHANGELOG_20160926-20160930.TXT`, and all file with name `FILE_CHANGELOG_*.TXT` will be merging and add separate new line into one file too like `FILE_CHANGELOG_20160926-20160930.TXT`.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
cat filename1 filename2 > filename3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something along those lines:

```
for prefix in CHANGELOG FILE_CHANGELOG; do
    ( for file in */"$prefix"_*.TXT; do
          echo "${file##*/}"
          cat "$file"
      done
    ) > "$prefix.TXT"
done
```